# How can I trigger a cloud function to send notification to android users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to send notifications manually to firebase app users. An option that I have thought of is to store the notification title, message and an array of the device notification tokens in the firebase cloud database and then use database onWrite() trigger to send the notification to the users. As per the firebase [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-limitationshttps://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-limitations).

A child in firebase can hold a maximum of 10mb data, which gives 2.5 million to 10 million characters. A single notification token has 152 characters. So, at this rate, the maximum number of devices would be 16447 - 65789 that I can send notifications to.

Is there any other workaround to this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you found, so it's hard to help. Most developers store the FCM tokens in separate nodes in the database, and this never even get close to the 10Mb per value limit. For an example of this, see this [Cloud Functions use-case](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens). I'd also recommend looking at the most up-to-date documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry about the confusion. What I meant was I'm trying to use database onWrite as a trigger to send notifications with the Firebase Admin SDK and so, to do that, I was going to store all the notification tokens (devices that notifications will be sent to) in a node and use that to send notifications wherein the problem lies with the 10 mb per child limit. 

Is there any other workaround for sending notifications manually from a client web application?

Comment: If you store the JSON as `{ "tokens": { "token1": true, "token2": true, "token3": true, ... } }` then there is no reasonable limit on the number of tokens you can store. The limit of 10mb is per **value**, which in this structure is `true`.